# Unidirectional one to many mapping with joinColumn

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

As per hibernate docs, the hibernatenate team strongly suggest not to use one to many unidirectional mapping without the join table. I would like to know is this because of performace issues or is there any other reasons behind it.

Say if have an employee who can have many phone no.s so to have this mapping I'll have

```
@Entity
public class Employee { 
...
 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name="employee_fk")
 public List<Phone> phones;
 ...
 }

@Entity
public class Phone { 
...
}
```

Hibernate will generate phone table with foreign key so I dont see any problem here. Also I don't want to have phone class having the employee property. 
Hibernate team advises to use a join table in such case, but why should i create one table unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a design question than a performance question. If you consider that a Phone doesn't know about the employee it's assigned to, this means that the Phone entity is independant from the Employee entity. And if it's independant from the Employee entity, its table shouldn't have a foreign key to the Employee table.

Moreover, since a Phone doesn't know about its employee, it means that it could potentially be reused and be associated with other kinds of entities: companies, customers, etc. It would be questionable to have foreign keys to all the entities that can have a phone in the phone table itself.

Answer (score 2):

In case of a unidirectional mapping hibernate will hit DB twice,

for a new phone no of the same employee John,it will do somthing like this

insert a new phone no in phn no table

update the employee id(john) with this phn no in phn no table

Further more you need map your phone persistence class and register with a particular employee otherwise your phone class will be reused,which i guess you dont want to do.